# Why am I receiving a warning that I could be blocked?

Tags: support, post-ban

I was just faced with a message on the Ask Question page:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more. For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question? Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

However, I checked my [last questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2409333/roman-matveev?tab=questions) and none of them have downvotes or "possible duplicate" penalties (or this case can not be considered as a 'penalty'?).

I have had some bad questions in my past, but I am surprised to see such a warning now.

How can I make sure what is really wrong with my account?

Comment: Did you recently delete questions?

Comment: What about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053669/why-gcc-compiles-code-in-a-wrong-way)? Together with your deleted posts, that'll weigh against you.

Comment: You do have a significant number of closed and deleted questions from the distant past.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, How can I see my deleted questions list?

Comment: @RomanMatveev: you can only see posts deleted in the past 60 days; there is a link at the bottom of your questions tab for deleted questions.

Comment: @BoltClock In this case why am I received this warning just now?

Comment: @RomanMatveev: probably because your [most recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882698/removing-wrong-dated-messages-from-skype-history) has received close votes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK I found two deleted questions. Deleting questions is bad anyway?

Comment: @Roman Matveev: No idea. Just make sure you put as much work into your next few questions as you can. Good luck.

Comment: @RomanMatveev: Deleted questions is *one indicator*; if those questions are salvageable you should certainly try to do so.

Comment: I did delete a question before because someone think my question is not good and no further answered, after several days, I found answer from other website, so I delete my question and hope not to waste others' time to solve the problem, is it not recommended to do so? What should I do for this in the next time?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do questions deleted manually by the OPS penalize him? Or just ones deleted automatically by the system?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. Others may find it useful in the future.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I don't know if the system weighs self-deletion any different from system-deletion.

Comment: related: [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days)

Comment: I got that warning but it disappeared so I thought my cleanup was okay. Then without warning I got question limit that actually is a question BAN.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is what your last 10 questions look like right now:

[image]

2 downvoted, 4 closed, 2 with a positive score, 6 with no score at all. Average score: -0.4.

That's not *awful*, but it's definitely not great either. If the trend continues, you're gonna end up blocked. So, we warn you ahead of time so that you can *do* something about it: fix your previous questions and ask better questions in the future.

If you don't think your history looks concerning, then feel free to ignore the warning... Just know that it's a lot harder to lift the ban *after* you've hit it than it is to avoid it *beforehand*.

**Required reading:** https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OP, go with Shog's advice. I've faced it. Took me month answer a hell lot questions getting upvoted to lift that ban off me

Comment: You can't "fix" most questions. It's just not possible. (especially if n00b me happens to ask them on mse without knowing what I'm doing… question banned)

Comment: @bjb568, sure questions can be fixed. However, once one is banned, fixing might not really help if people don't revoke their downvotes, or if others don't upvote the fixed questions. However, the above warning is given *before* one is banned. So fixing old questions should at least ensure one does not get more downvotes on those old posts. (That is, if one has read and understood http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before editing those old posts.)

Comment: @Arjan You can't fix give me teh code, most opinion-based questions, and recommendation questions. The best thing to do is delete, which doesn't help the ban.

Comment: You can fix all of those, @bjb - it can be a lot of work, but it is possible. Few bother.

Comment: Maybe you can (I don't know how), but it's a waste of time when other things can be improved and unhelpable(with a reasonable amount of effort) crap can be deleted.

Comment: The onus is always on the person asking, @bjb. If they don't care about other people's time that they're wasting, they can just keep plowing forward into the ban.

Comment: What if they made a mistake but suddenly got enlightened (or something)? Reputation from voting is gone'd when the post is deleted. Shouldn't progress to the question ban be reversed if you deleted your own post, showing that you know better now? Of course if the post is deleted by the community (not Community) that should count toward the ban.

Comment: What if, what if... What if they just *demonstrate* it, @bjb? The vast majority of folks hitting the ban - or the warning - can get out of it with one or two up-votes, one question re-opened, literally just a few minutes invested in making some edits... The problem isn't that folks can't learn, it's that [they don't learn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172300/what-happens-to-folks-who-get-question-banned-by-and-large/172773#172773). You wanna bet on folks having learned something when the odds are heavily against that; I'd rather bet on someone who has at least done *something*.

Comment: I'm banned on MSE (voting is different, but what I posted was crap anyway). Answer with 25 votes? The system doesn't care. There is no way I'm going to do a anything with my questions, even if I wanted to, I don't have the links. I've always been against permanent bans, a 30-day ban works much better. The bad askers will just leave. The good ones get a break to learn. Life in jail is useless, you may as well kill them.

Comment: Nothing permanent about it, @bjb. Meta's an odd case, because we let you dig and dig and dig before you get blocked - meaning you have a long, long hill to climb before you get *unblocked*. But that's just a reflection of the voting patterns there. You'll get out of it eventually...

Comment: It's permanent if nothing is done. With crap deleted questions, that should be default behavior. Meta lets you get upvotes very quickly, like how you can get downvotes very quickly. Answerable questions are hard to find, but that's the same on SO.

Comment: I recently have seen this too on my profile and I personally feel like I am a positive contributor to SO. Without asking basically this same question for myself here on MSO, what can you suggest for me? My average score on answers is .875 per answer. My average score on questions is .6 per question. Both are positive.

Comment: Deleting your bad questions doesn't help?

Comment: I just got three up votes on my newest question, so I'm not worried about it anymore, but I don think it was excessive that it was warning me when there wasn't really a problem in the first place.

Comment: I wish there was a way to differentiate between a down vote from someone who personally didn't like the question, and a down vote for a question that was written in a manner that is unhelpful. More than once I would ask a clear question, but the people "answering" keep trying to draw the question into irrelevant territory. They ask for more and more useless information and down vote when they dont get it and then I end up having to answer my own question when I figure it out. So now I am at risk of being banned, not because of poor questions, but poor readers.

Comment: @Elliander That's a *very* bold statement to make. Is your clear question really clear? Why would anyone downvote after answering? If they found it worth answering, I doubt they were among the downvoters. I could take a look at some of your questions as a third party if you like.

Comment: @Elliander I often ask people for more code because I want to help but I do not have a clear understanding of what the OPS is trying to do. One or two lines of code often leaves out details that can clear up any confusion I have. I suggest that when you ask a question you should create a short example which others can copy and paste and compile and run themselves. Much time would saved if more people would do this. For one thing, a potential answerer will have an immediate understanding of what you are trying to do and will be more likely able to answer your question immediately without commen

Comment: @brad-larson Can I ask why what I posted earlier was voted down and deleted? I posted it as an answer because I didn't think it was an appropriate comment on the OP and I didn't want to post it as a new question which would be near identical to the one here which I understand to be regarded as very bad practice. If that was the problem then a heads up on it would have been useful rather than a deletion without explanation

I asked it as I was concerned as I wanted to stop doing whatever was causing my warning it but it now looks as if asking for help with it  has made my position worse:(

Comment: Your last question prior to today [was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623095/sql-server-firewall-blocking-replication-even-with-port-1433-allowed) @mharran - that's the reason for the warning.

Comment: @Shog9 Thank you for that explanation.

It seems a bit harsh that I should get threatened with being blocked for asking a question that would have been better asked on another StackOverflow forum.

Comment: Just to add to that last comment, having been a moderator elsewhere, I appreciate the often thankless effort that moderatorion involves but I think there should be some way for users to find out the specific reasons behind a warning.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Worth thinking about.