# I have deleted my question from Stack Overflow and now I'm unable to ask any more questions

Tags: support

This warning appears when I ask a question

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Comment: Is that just a warning, and are you actually *able* to post new questions, or are you already banned from doing so?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - that's the warning, telling users they are **close** to getting into a ban.

Comment: sir but I deleted all Question now no more question to edit.. :( when I m going to ask new Question warning shows above mentioned and i cant ask any more question

Comment: @IrfanAli so undelete them and improve them.

Comment: The point is to *improve* them, not completely rewrite them to ask a different question. That makes existing answers irrelevant and out of context.

Comment: Refer Shog's answer here [How can I understand why am I receiving a warning that I could be blocked?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked)

Comment: You are doing invalid edits to your questions - http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23533359/9. Take some time, read the comments again and put some time in writing the questions.

Comment: yes i made some worse edit im stuk :(

Comment: You're not making it better by rolling back edits that make your *answers* more readable.

Comment: yes but still i lost my reputation at editing some question

Answer (score 8):

You **are** able to ask questions.

The warning is telling you that you need to make sure that it is a **good** question, **otherwise** you may end up getting blocked from asking any new questions.

Read the articles linked. Make sure your question follows those guidelines.

If you don't, you risk getting question banned.

The system is trying to help you out here.

Comment: but how can i make correct the question ?? the question I deleted...

Comment: @IrfanAli - undelete it (on your profile page, in the questions tab, there is a link to show deleted recent questions), edit it and make it better. But I thought you were asking about posting **new** questions?

Comment: thanks alot @Oded i have done it :)

Comment: A shame you did not read the linked articles. The edits you made were bad and the questions were made **worse** by them. That is not *improving*.

Comment: yes i made some worse edit im stuk :(