# Wait 0 days before asking again. It's been five!

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, asking-questions, rate-limiting

My account won't let me post, claiming that I've asked two questions (actually I've asked fifteen) and that some of them have not been received well.

It's asking that I wait 0 days, however it's been on 0 days now for the past five! Does this mean I'm banned or something?

Edit: if this is a 'bug' what am I supposed to do?

> You have reached your question limit It looks like you might need a
>   break - take a breather and come back soon!
>
> You've asked 2 questions so far, some of which have not been received
>   very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and
>   it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions
>   have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking
>   questions entirely.
>
> It's been 5 days since you asked your last question, we ask that you
>   wait 0 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your
>   previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have
>   pointed out in comments.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542/839601)

Comment: Thanks for this, but it seems everyone else is getting a countdown (one days, two day etc) till they can next post, as opposed to me who has been stuck on 0 days for the past five!

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug.

Comment: If it's a bug, what you should do is tag your question as such. I've done that for you now. I've left the [meta-tag:support] tag because IMO it's also a support question.

Comment: Please don't put tags in titles

Comment: @Braiam If you check the [revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/272453/revisions), you'll see I didn't add the tag to the title. ChrisF's comment was addressed at the OP.

Comment: Yeah, that sure looks like a bug! We're looking into it.

Comment: @Giles Can you edit your question to include the exact message you're receiving?

Comment: @AnnaLear No worries! It's been added for you. Thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

We have tracked down a bug in the Question rate limit calculation that would impact people who have performed multiple edits on their own posts.  A fix has been deployed to production and you are no longer blocked, Giles.  Thanks for the report!

Comment: These guys are really efficient!