# Edit old questions to get new answers

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, post-ban, bump

I am currently banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow, and the Help Center suggested that I improve my existing questions.

These questions however, are pretty old now and aren't going to be shown in the first page on the site anyway. If I edit them to make improvements, will they be marked as new?

Comment: Editing does bump a question to the front page. With that in mind, try to make one big edit per post, and not several smaller ones, or you'll annoy people.

Comment: @Kendra: I just edited an old question that wasn't answered, and I couldn't see it in the front page .. ?

Comment: That might be because it was deleted, or it might be because of your tag interests, I'm not sure 100% how the front page algorithm works. I do know editing it will show it as "modified" and "active" so it should get more views now that you've edited it.

Comment: What tab are you on? Click on the "active" tab

Comment: @codeMagic: Oh! I see .. I see it now.

Comment: At a quick glance, I would recommend editing some of the titles to be a little more specific/clear, if you have not already thought to do so. Not all are bad but things like, "My code isn't working" aren't very good titles

Comment: On that note, "It doesn't work" is **never** a good problem statement. You need to say *exactly* what is wrong/confusing.

Comment: In any case, +1 for coming here to improve your questions :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET too verbose.  Try: `"It doesn't work" doesn't work.

Comment: Actually "It doesn't work" should automatically be filtered off before even posting a question. A feature request?

Comment: @Teemu: I think that would be helpful!

Comment: @Teemu: no it should not. Automatic filtering is generally a thing to avoid, it confuses users and does not teach them how to properly write a question. For instance, "I have tried xyz but it doesn't work. Instead of giving xxx, yyy happens." would be perfectly fine in a question.

Comment: @nico Well, the comment was actually half a joke (maybe a bad one?)... But seriously talking, something should be done, for example, I've crushed six sequential JS questions, where the only problem description was "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Teemu: agree, but what should be done is to teach people how to ask questions on the Internet. This is not a SO specific problem unfortunately...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That very first question that you asked was what was holding you down. Yeah, there's no way that could have been salvaged. However, it looks like some of your newer (and *much* better) questions managed to get some attention, and you're no longer blocked.

We've, fortunately, [fixed this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) for folks that have created accounts since mid-September. The way we *were* doing it didn't allow for how it can take folks a question or two in order to get used to what the community expects from questions, and how heavy voting can be.

We now slow you down a bit and let you know where you're going wrong, *way* before you hit the block that won't lift until your average score improves, or the question weighing you down falls out of scope of the check.

After you've asked a couple of questions, the system starts looking at how well your posts are being received, how often you ask, how often you tend to go back and edit your previous posts, and how inclined you are to provide good answers to other questions. If you're not doing so well with your questions, you'll be asked to wait 1, 2 .. 3 .. up to 7 days before asking more, depending on your participation, and pile-on down voting doesn't hurt you as much as it did.

You would have been rate-limited at least three times before being blocked, which is three chances you could have taken to prioritize editing your posts or providing some answers, had something prodded you.

The good news is we're *pretty receptive* to helping those that are stuck in this scenario, those that just got off to a bit of a rough start, but have more than demonstrated that they can ask better questions. It's only fair, because since September, new users have *much* more help afforded to them and it appears to be working well (data still coming in). More and more, users that move on to the more persistent block are *generally* the type that just don't (and probably won't) get it - that's been the goal since we introduced the whole concept of post blocks.

Anyway, good on you for trying as you have, and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 2):

They won't be marked as new, but they **will** show up under the "Active" tab on the front page as "modified".