# Question ban algorithm really should be changed…?

Tags: support, feature-request, asking-questions, post-ban

Since about three weeks go, I'm abruptly, without warning, not able to ask questions.  I have read all of the (very unclear) information and see no chance to break the "ban".

It seems as questions are handled completely separated from answers...?

I have a reputation over 200 but a negative score for my questions (+1 vs -3).  I have one question with -2, one question with -1 and one question with +1 (=-2).

Negative voted questions:

- [SqlClient vs web-service…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481313/sqlclient-vs-web-service)
  and
- [How to get JQuery-UI to work with ASP.NET MVC6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943930/how-to-get-jquery-ui-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc6)

First, I wanted to delete the questions, what is not possible, as I have received answers already (and, it seems, also would not affect my voting positively anyway).  Then, I flagged the -2 question for attention (and never received any feedback).

So according to the information I have seen, "the system automatically break the ban, if the reputation becomes positive".  I **have** a positive reputation overall.  How should I turn my *question* score to positive, if I'm not able to:

- delete the bad voted questions (with answers)?
- post new questions
  (that - maybe - becomes positive upvotes)?

I also don’t know how I should edit my *old* questions to receive up votes.

There are many postings to this problem here (I don’t want to post all links…) with similar questions (most marked as duplicate and… down voted of course), so maybe something is wrong with the algorithm?

I have helped some other users with my answers and have a positive reputation.
I need to be able to post some new questions, as I have just started with MVC6.
I haven't done anything bad (but helped other users with my answers).  This problem has cost me all together over a full day now.

I understand that some rules should be in place to uphold the quality, but not in this way.

My Proposal:

- The overall reputation should be counted.
- The user should receive a (clear) warning before the ban takes place. E.G.
  “Warning: Your reputation to questions is already negative. If you post new questions that are down voted then, you may receive a question ban. So be careful, what you ask”.
- The user should be able to delete down voted questions (also if they have received answers) or down votes should not count, if they have some answers (so the “bad question” then is “cleaned” in SO).

Can somebody give me a *clear* advise how to break my ask ban?

Comment: And also (or even more) [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days)

Comment: Why should reputation factor in at all? Bad posts are bad regardless of how much rep someone has. You should also have seen messages about bad/deleted posts counting against you.

Comment: As I wrote, I HAVE read the other postings and you can see in all the other ("duplicate") postings, that the problem is NOT clear and confuses a lot of users. Further I have posted a PROPOSAL to CHANGE the algorithm. Change the algorithm, and you don't will have questions to the problem and also no more duplicates.

Comment: One thing we cannot see here are your deleted questions/answers. They also count towards a ban - do you have some of them too?

Comment: "I have flagged the -2 question for attention": You improving or failing to improve does not require intervention of a diamond moderator, so the flag was simply inappropriate. "the system automatically break the ban, if the reputation becomes positive": Where did you get that? The system recalculates whether a new question by you, considering past contributions, is too likely to be a waste. Your reputation does not in any way factor into that, aside from a high-rep user having lots of positive contributions. Also, questions are weighed more for the asking privilege, but answers *do* count.

Comment: The first question you linked to was too broad for sure and I was the last close voter on that one, I still stand by that vote. Your other visible question can't be reproduced by commenters on your question. In that sense it is unclear which is a valid reason to down vote.

Comment: "...it is not possible to receive constructive help here..." Sorry you're having a negative experience this morning, but this is only one question. To say that it is impossible to receive constructive help here is to ignore thousands of other questions where people did receive help. People just disagree with your proposal. It's nothing personal.

Comment: You are learning about the "meta-effect" now as well. Today is a big learning day!

Comment: As for your flag, it was declined with the following reason on the 14th: "You can delete it yourself by unaccepting the answer, refreshing, and then deleting, but that will not help with the question ban. You should edit your existing questions to improve them instead." You can see that in your user profile.

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks for your constructive posting. No.. as far I can see, I don't have deleted questions ("No deleted recent questions").

Comment: @BilltheLizard: With "no constructive help" I dont mean the down votes to THIS meta-posting, I mean the additional down votes to my OLD questions in SO (links in my posting), just minutes after doing the post. So I have now -6 (or maybe more) to my OLD questions instead of -2 before my posting. So I'm dead to post new questions no (after this posting) anyway - really nice...

Comment: @FredyWenger - You have this downvoted and deleted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386269/how-to-start-developing-with-xamarin-forms-vs

Comment: I'd go ahead and delete that question before it gets any worse, since this question is still near the top spot on Meta. It's usually not a good idea to draw attention to a negatively voted question unless you've at least tried to edit into better shape first. (You can still edit it while it's deleted, then undelete it later.)

Comment: Putting your two (atrocious) questions up on a meta post ranting about how they were unfairly downvoted is the best way to get dozens more downvotes on them very quickly.

Comment: @BradLarson: Thanks - I have not found it in my profile (how can I see it in my profile?) But anyway... it don't help (or what can I do with the deleted messages) and now I'm dead anyway to ask questions (of cause the further down votes to my old questions)...

Comment: @FredyWenger Your profile shows you only "recent" deleted posts, which I recall means they cannot be more than 60 days old. I make a habit of checking my deleted posts from time to time, just in case there's a surprise there.

Comment: @BradLarson: In my deleted post I wanted to post a link to my documentation to Xamarin (started-guide for new user), what - it seems so - is not allowed in SO. So what should I do with it... I think undelete make no sense as the content is not "allowed"...?

Comment: @louis: Thanks,  now, I know that.

Comment: *Can somebody give me a clear advise* - Can you explain what's unclear in the dupe?

Comment: @BSMP: I still don't know, what I can do. I can't delete the questions (and it further don't would have any effect). In my deleted question, I have posted a link to a documentation (to help other users), that is not allowed (so I can undelete it and receive further down votes). One of the questions is too broad (should I change the question to a completely different question or... what... does this make sense...?)

Comment: The text for the "too broad" close reason gives advice on how to fix it, *"Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."* http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 17):

> the user should be able to delete down voted questions (also if they
>   have received answers) or down votes should not count, if they have
>   some answers (so the “bad question” then is “cleaned” in SO)

So known bad users can keep asking questions? No, the question ban is there exactly to prevent that. Deleting your questions is not a solution or permission to keep asking bad questions.

> the user should receive a (clear) warning before the ban take place.
>   E.G. “Warning: Your reputation to questions is already negative. If
>   you post new questions that are down voted then, you may receive a
>   question ban. So... be careful, what you ask”.

Iirc something like this already exists, and you overlooked it.

> the overall reputation should be counted in

Overall score is counted in. Reputation is deliberately skewed towards gaining reputation more then loosing it. Otherwise a downvote would cost you -10.

Comment: I don't say, that the user should be able to post one bad question after the other. This should be prevented, but not so as implemented yet. I never have received a warning before the ban. My questions are not as bad that I should receive a ban for them (one ist "to broad"). But... as I have received more down votes (from "nice" users) to my already down voted questions, just minutes after my posting, I'm dead do post further questions anyway...

Comment: @FredyWenger You can improve your current questions and make them better so they get better score or reopened.

Comment: "Iirc something like this already exists, and you overlooked it." http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230660 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118