# Why is my question getting so much hate?

Tags: discussion

So I recently asked this question: [Rewriting a conditional chain as a sequence of one-liners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187636/rewriting-a-conditional-chain-as-a-sequence-of-one-liners)

As you can see, it has a ton of down votes, which have banned me from asking questions for 5 days.

I asked @dasblinkenlight (the user who posted the answer which I accepted) in a comment why he thought there were so many down votes.

He said that he thought it was a good question, and he had no idea why there were so many down votes. He said that members will often down vote because they don't like that particular coding style.

**I'm struggling to understand why people hate my question so much. I would think this is the kind of question that would deserve such treatment: [How to increase the project tango tablet USB2.0 OTG output current/voltage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189739/how-to-increase-the-project-tango-tablet-usb2-0-otg-output-current-voltage)**

Comment: One bad question wouldn't get you banned...would it?

Comment: You have no way of knowing, unless someone who downvoted clarifies, _exactly_ why your question was downvoted. dasblinkenlight gave you a _possible_ explanation, but there may be something else wrong that even they aren't catching. The best anyone can tell you is wait five days, review and see if you can improve your previous questions during that time, and review the help center to see if you can find anything else that could be an issue with your question.

Comment: @Paulie_D No, it would not.  It might get you rate limited though (which is the case here).  That said, this user has two (undeleted) questions with a negative score, not just one.

Comment: @Louis Actually, this is a rate limit, so [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) is more appropriate

Comment: @Kendra Right. I took the OP's use of "banned" at face value.

Comment: Where are you getting the 5 days from?

Comment: @JonClements - That's what it says when I try to ask a question.

Comment: *He said that members will often down vote because they don't like that particular coding style.* - What they might have meant was that you could have gotten down votes because people thought you were *literally* asking if you could separate lines of Java with a comma (hence the first comment asking if you'd tried it) rather than just an approximation of what you were trying to achieve. People may have thought it was a "will this run" question.

Comment: @BSMP - Ahhhh! Okay! Now I see. That was very helpful!

Comment: Given that the accepted answer also begins with "this would not compile", you'll want to make it clearer when you're writing pseudo-code or code you know won't work and shouldn't be taken literally.

Comment: @BSMP - This is the kind of stuff that should be added to the FAQ. Could you tell me if there is anything else that could be improved in my question? I want to learn for next time.

Comment: To be clear, that's still a guess. I just think the responses to your question back up my guess. Other than that, there's a set of links at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask that should be helpful. Also compare your original question to the edits someone made.

Comment: What are you doing now, exactly? Are you going to edit this every time you find a sub-par question? I hate to break it to you, but there are literally thousands upon thousands of questions out there that should be closed/deleted, but aren't. Community moderation isn't perfect. You should be satisfied (thrilled, actually) that you got 5 upvotes for such a basic question, and just drop it.

Comment: @MikeM. - No, but that question is completely off topic and has only one downvote.

Comment: It's only got the [google-project-tango] tag, so not many people are going to see it. It's only been viewed 29 times as of now, and given the percentage of users who have the close-vote privilege, I'd say the fact that it does have one VtC already is pretty good. Posts like this will eventually get deleted by the roomba, if it doesn't get enough attention to deal with it normally. (I just VtC'd it, btw.)

Comment: @AndroidDev, please stop updating your question with other bad questions. As Mike M. (no relation) noted, we know that there are other bad questions. There are more bad questions than there are people who recognize the questions as bad. Those users will also get rate-limited if they continue to post bad questions and are downvoted by those who find them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I have been banned from asking questions for 5 days because several users don't like my coding style.

No, you've been limited from asking questions for 5 days because several users didn't like some of your questions.  One user *guesses* that it is related to your coding style, but it's just that, a guess.

> What to do?

Choose any combination of the following:

- Wait 5 days before asking another question.
- Improve the quality of your contributions such that you are no longer rate limited.
- Ensure that future contributions you do make are in line with the community's standards and expectations, so that they are better received than your previous content.

Comment: Actually 1 and 3 are one and the same. If he doesn't meet the community standards when the 5 days are up, he's more likely to be rate-limited again or just question banned.

Comment: **Please tell me if you see anything wrong with the question I mentioned in the title.** I guess on Stack Overflow people like downvoting, my contributions seem to be well received on Ask Ubuntu...

Comment: @Braiam 3 is only an option after doing either 1 or 2 (unless you consider that advise to apply to contributions other than questions, i.e. answers).  I considered that obvious enough to not bother stating it explicitly.

Comment: @AndroidDev Or perhaps you're just better at answering Ubuntu related questions than you are programming questions.

Comment: @AndroidDev or they aren't the wiser.

Comment: @AndroidDev Sure.  The point is the same.

Comment: @AndroidDev I can't know why others choose to vote on your question as they did anymore than anyone else can.  They can only guess.  The most we can say is that they felt that the question, "Does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  I would guess that "unclear" probably isn't the issue in your case, and that it's likely the other two points, but again, that's just my guess.

Comment: I know this is a few years old but I was looking for something and I found someone that posted a question about the same thing I was looking for and recently. Annnd Without a second guess it was marked as duplicate. I find it really annoying that people are so quick to mark as duplicate when the question that they point you to is out of date by a few years.

Comment: @Greg432 I'm glad you were able to find the solution to your problems quickly and easily by being directed there through a duplicate question.