# Do flags on old questions get ignored?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I raised a flag for [this question(How to increase the project tango tablet USB2.0 OTG output current/voltage
)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189739/how-to-increase-the-project-tango-tablet-usb2-0-otg-output-current-voltage) a couple of months ago.

This post was originally reported (or complained) by [this question(Why is my question getting so much hate?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322925/why-is-my-question-getting-so-much-hate) in MSO.

I strongly believe this question is not suitable for SO.

But unfortunately my flag was ignored and aged away.

[image: aged away flag]

The (ridiculous) question and answer are still there.

[image: off topic question]

**Is this question is too old for flags or is it considered to be an OK question in SO?**

Comment: there are not enough reviewers, specially close vote reviewers, that are available and willing to sift through all the raised flags on a daily basis, week after week, month after month, year after year. Some flags might be expedited by bringing them to a chatroom but SOCVR for example wouldn't have accepted your cv-pls as [the question wasn't recently active](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-cv-pls-not-a-habit).

Comment: The question is finally closed after 4 years. All I wanted to do is that.

Comment: Meta is here to help you ;)

Comment: You can try re-flagging it, but unfortunately the crap comes in faster than reviewers can shovel it so sometimes things just won't get handled.