# I asked three questions and got banned. Why?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have asked only three questions yet and only one received an upvote. The rest are neither downvoted nor flagged or anything. Then, why I am getting this message?

> You have a history of asking low quality questions. Please put more thought, time, and effort into your questions. To help you do this, the number of questions you may ask per week is currently limited. For more information, visit the Help Center.

Why is it getting downvoted? [That post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) says that if my questions are poorly received, then does that mean that I will not get banned if my questions are upvoted only and **normal questions are received as poor questions?**

Comment: Any deleted questions? Those count too.

Comment: I don't have any

Comment: this is my second question in this week

Comment: Given you have no deleted questions, and have questions with scores 0, 0, and +2, asked across the space of a month, I admit this seems pretty unfair. I'm not sure whether other accounts on your IP range have any affect on this message (there are a few accounts on your range which are question blocked).

Comment: @Matt there are a few accounts on your range which are question blocked , what this means actually?

Comment: @Matt IIRC, answer bans don't decay, no? That'd mean unless OP edits _a lot_ or asks _a lot_ of good questions, they'd be banned forever.

Comment: @Magisch: This is a **question** ban; although not a full question ban, a "limited to one question a week" ban. As to whether either of those decay... I'm not sure.

Comment: @Matt I thought OP had an _answer_ ban. And those are iirc full and non-decaying.

Comment: @n00b: there are other Stack Overflow users which share your IP address (IP addresses can be reassigned to different Internet connections, so this alone doesn't mean much). Some of those users are blocked from asking questions (due to a poor question-asking record). To a user which has only 1 account, this might seem irrelevant, but historically, a question-blocked user could simply create another account to bypass his ban; therefore many blocks now are on an IP level, rather than a user account level.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the duplicate does not provide an answer for this specific case.

Comment: @Matt: How would that work in any reasonable way, considering most non-organisational users have a dynamic IP?

Comment: @Olaf - You'd be surprised at how reliable IP association between accounts is. Almost always, sock puppet accounts and question-ban evasion accounts will come from the same IP as the main account. Even with dynamic IPs, they don't change often enough to mask this. For example, this account was pretty clearly the third or fourth question-ban evasion account of a troublesome user (thus them going bye-bye), and it looks like the system worked exactly as expected.

Comment: Looks like [that meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) needs to be updated to mention that, *No No You can't create a new account and evade a ban*, @Brad.

Comment: @BradLarson: Ok, I just commented on solely relying on the IP. But I very well asume there is more behind that and you cannot reveal all details as that would help to work around them. We just can judge from what is stated and have to rely on you mods. That's what makes it so important you comment on a specific problem with the relevant details. Thank you for doing that!

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine you'd call public attention to this situation if you understood that you were "trying to abuse the system by creating multiple puppets and question-ban evasion accounts" (the result of @BradLarson's investigation, quote from Matt's answer below). Assuming Brad is right, was something not clear about what's considered good SO behavior, and how bans work?

Comment: @henry, no. Some users are just that arrogant and stupid.

Comment: Well, color me silly for completely falling for it. The abusers are getting good at feigning ignorance on meta, I truly felt sorry for the guy :/

Comment: And this meta post is unfairly downvoted too.

Answer (score 14):

Given you have no deleted questions, and have questions with scores 0, 0, and +2, asked across the space of a month, I admit this seems pretty unfair.

Your block may or may not be affected by other Stack Overflow users which share your IP address (IP addresses can be reassigned to different Internet connections, so this alone doesn't mean much), as some of those users are blocked from asking questions (due to a poor question-asking record).

Since moderators cannot lift question blocks (see [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days)), and since you're still allowed to ask 1 question a week, which isn't too unreasonable; my suggestion is to simply make that 1 question count.

Comment: This doesn't just "seem" unfair, this **is** unfair. (As well as highly frustrating)

Comment: @Seth - Except for the fact that this was indeed someone trying to abuse the system by creating multiple puppets and question-ban evasion accounts. There are false positives, but after investigation it turns out this wasn't one. In any case, it only applies to brand new accounts, and once you're above a low threshold you don't need to worry about this anymore.

Comment: @BradLarson Ah, thanks alot :) I'm still not sure about this system though, as it does seem a bit risky (glad it worked out in this case though!).

Comment: @Seth worth keeping in mind that there is safe and easy way to hop over new user restrictions by suggesting edits. It's not that one is locked and there is no way out. No matter how many classmates push through the school IP, there is always a way to those willing to put an effort and get personal access