# What's the relationship between the number of days Stack Overflow suspends an account (ask question suspension) and the fault committed by that user?

Tags: support, post-ban, rate-limiting

I would like to know what's the criteria for banning an account for a certain amount of days (x) - being x <= infinite.

And if any person incurs again, his/her account can be deleted forever? What are the criteria for don't let a person ask a question for 3 days, 4 days or 6 days...?
It's that a random number?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: There are a number of articles on this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans, https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans, plus FAQs like [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542), the abovementioned [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583), [Before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254262), which are found on the [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225).

Comment: Are you asking about question bans, or account suspensions?  They are two very different things.

Comment: I specified it in the parenthesis (ask question suspension) I couldn't find the answer I was expecting but a user stated that Stack Overflow hides the details of how the number of days a suspension length is calculated

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/ says, account suspensions can be from 1 to 365 days (or longer, now, I think) at the discretion of the suspending moderator. Question bans don't have a time limit, they are based on quality of your contributions. Improve the quality of your contributions and the ban will lift automatically, just like it was placed.

Comment: I was referring to the temporal suspension time for asking new questions (1-7 days) But thank you anyway

Comment: I think you want that first FAQ link in Mike's comment then. The confusion here is that we don't refer to it as a suspension when a user is only prevented from asking (or answering). In that case it's either a rate limit or a ban. The term suspension is used when the user isn't allowed to do anything on the site at all.

Comment: Oh, my bad then for confusing the terms.

Comment: The relation is this: if you made more serious, or more times, or you are critic of the system, then the punishment is longer.

Answer (score 4):

In [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) it says:

> #### How is the length of time that I'm limited actually calculated?
>
> It's based on your average question score, how long you tend to wait between asking questions, how well you participate in other ways on the site, and how often you tend to revisit and improve your posts, even the positively scored ones. We don't provide the actual formula and details, only because we want folks to focus on what the system is trying to tell them, rather than trying to find ways around it.
>
> Rate limits vary from 1 to 7 days.

And now to answer your questions:

- And if any person incurs again, his/her account can be deleted forever?

Account deletion is a manual process once an account has had some activity. Before an account is deleted you probably had (several) warnings from a real human in your inbox and/or e-mail. Ignoring those warnings increases the chance of deletion but that still needs a human to click *nuke account*.

- What are the criteria for don't let a person ask a question for 3 days, 4 days or 6 days...? It's that a random number?

> We don't provide the actual formula and details