# New users have terrible experiences on SO, and will ultimately be the downfall of this site

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

It may not seem like it, but making it hard for new members to be part of your community is the first step in the downfall of an empire.

Why do I say this?

Because, so far my experience has been nothing but negative and I've only asked two questions on here. My first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194011/what-exactly-is-ngif-doing-in-angular) got me ban from asking questions, and my second question (trying to find out why I was temp-ban) was deleted within a matter of minutes with no real response that answered what I was asking.

The algorithms that you have in place to prevent bots/harassment on your sight is to strong, and is banning people who haven't committed the violations you are trying to target.

On a funny side note, since I've been trying to find out why my first question got me ban, people have been following my link and down-voting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are we being "elitist"? Is there something wrong with that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262446/are-we-being-elitist-is-there-something-wrong-with-that)

Comment: It didn't get you a ban, it only asked you to wait 4 days before asking the next one. Those are different things.

Comment: *"On a funny side note, since I've been trying to find out why my first question got me ban, people have been following my link and down-voting it."* that is the meta effect. You provided a link to your post to users who are more than happy to use the moderation tools available to them. Sometimes it is positive, other times it is negative. depends on the post.

Comment: One question cannot cause a question ban.  It *might* cause a rate limit, but not an outright ban.

Comment: For some reason I marked your earlier meta post as favorite: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373735/why-have-i-been-ban-from-asking-questions-from-so it has that handy screenshot from Shog9.

Comment: So it *was* a rate limit @rene.  Good to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Comment: New users don't have a terrible experience.  People consistantly asking low quality questions that don't belong on the site, who feel entitled to be able to do so and refuse to accept the possibility that they should be improving the quality of their contributions or following the rules, tend to have a terrible experience.  The new users that ask good questions, who are willing to hear constructive criticisms of problems with their contributions, and who strive to correct those problems, tend to have great experiences with the site.

Comment: @Servy I think the "terrible experience" here is relative. Anything short of being spoon-fed an answer, a back massage, and a $100 will be considered a "terrible experience" for some users.

Comment: see also: [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271543/839601)

Comment: @Mysticial:  I still haven't received my $100. :(

Comment: @Mysticial my question got answered and I was happy. It had positive upvotes until I started asking why I was temporary ban. There are a lot of nasty people on here.

Comment: @rene that is a temporary-ban and nothing less.

Comment: @HappySheep if you were given a temporary ban, you wouldn't be posting here.  So no, it's not.

Comment: It matters a lot but you'll experience the difference in 4 days if you ask your next badly received question.

Comment: Don't worry. this will be my last question @rene

Comment: @happysheep see it how you want, but 'ban' is used for a different thing, where you are only allowed one post every 6 months to try and get out of the ban. What you experienced is rate limiting. If only to use the same language as us, so we can speak about the same thing, it might be better to change the wording you use.

Comment: Have you not considered that the amount of negativity you received is proportional to how much the community thinks you need to improve your questions rather than how much the community dislikes you personally?

Comment: @HappySheep Feel free to come back if you want, but please be prepared to be open to the possibility that _you_ might have to change the way you post.

Comment: I can count the number of times a new user complains about a hostile environment, and actually *tried* to ask a good question, on one hand.  We have differing expectations here at SE; we expect you to put effort into your questions.  You expect to get help regardless of your level of investment.  That collides, and you're left with a bad experience.  We won't lower our quality standards, so if you want to get help, it's in your best interests to try to meet those standards.

Comment: @Wurd ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: You're missing the point. My question was up-voted until I asked why I got temporary ban from it. I'm trying to express that I I got temp ban for an illegitimate reason @Wurd

Comment: To the delete voters:  I'm not convinced this yet rises to the level of *deletion*.  Perhaps we should keep this around as an example?

Comment: Yup, and this is the climax of this post. It's now on hold because everyone is thinking i'm complaining about downvotes but i'm really trying to express I got temp ban for no reason xD

Comment: @Makoto why exactly this one? I don't see we're getting anyway here. And I'm one of the delete voters so far, so if it gets deleted, blame me.

Comment: I don't think you're exactly being honest with people here. This is your third or fourth account, so this isn't your first experience with the site. You had a chance to ask 13 questions on your first account, a few on your second before it was deleted, this one on your third, and were prevented from recreating the second account. If this continues, you will encounter more severe rate limits, so I highly recommend going back to your first account and improving the questions there.

Comment: @rene:  Something to use the next time Tim Post or another CM decides that we're being too mean to new users of the site.  This ain't the first time this kind of thing has happened and it's - not sure if there's a word besides "dehumanizing" that I can use here - that ***this*** side of the discussion is just cast aside so carelessly.

Comment: Of course you're not getting anywhere, because you're all so focused on downvotes and molding to SE format when I'm just trying to show I got temp ban for no real reason @rene

Comment: Ahh, so there's more to the story than we're being told.  Not too surprised at that, to be honest.

Comment: @HappySheep You could have asked "did I do something wrong? What can I do better?" instead of immediately accusing the site of being terrible. Be constructive and be prepared to learn something.

Comment: @HappySheep you don't get a temp ban for no reason. Your question got 4 down votes and 3 upvotes yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52194011/timeline. that is the sole reason you got rate limited and those votes happened way before you posted here on meta. Please don't try to rewrite history, that is not appreciated and not needed.

Comment: @Makoto Ok, with the excellent comment from Brad this has become a valuable example. If I only could retract my delete vote ...

Comment: If the site downfall comes to pass, where will the deadbeats get their homework done?   So many 'developers' will get fired for sudden, overnight, gross incompetence:(

Comment: @MartinJames That could actually be good for those of us who do know what we're doing; all of a sudden, our talent pool shrinks dramatically, pushing up demand greatly!

Comment: Of course.... There's more to it than meets the eye. So the site is giving terrible experiences, but you've had 4 chances to correct your behavior, probably lots of comments about how to better write your posts... but we're all horrible monsters... right...

Comment: @Patrice Dozens, not four.  Dozens.  Each account didn't just get one chance.

Comment: I deleted your first question on meta so that you'd have a chance to read the message without getting dumped on here for being careless. You ARE slowly improving in your asking... But you've got a ways to go. We're giving you as much help as we're able to; you have to meet us half way. There's no way around that.

Comment: The OP didn't keep his/her word. The last (visible) post is [from March 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247706/changing-from-a-default-theme-to-a-custom-theme-removes-cursor-from-matinput-an) (about six month later). (It being close to the question ban limit period could be a coincidence.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

rene managed to [keep a link to the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373735/why-have-i-been-ban-from-asking-questions-from-so) that you had earlier on this matter.  For the < 10K users, in context:  this isn't a question ban, this is a **rate limit**.

[image]

Instead of flaming us and insisting that the algorithms are somehow evil, reading the advice here and taking a break would be best for all of us.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't be of any more service to you.  I wish you the best of luck in your online help endeavors.  Should you wish to return to the site with a fresh slate, we'll still be here.

Comment: If you're wondering why there's a rate-limit in the first place. Please understand that the # of new users posting questions far out-number the ability of the community to answer them. Without limits, the entire site would turn into a toilet that's too clogged for even a plunger to clear. So the system actually slows down *everybody*, not just new users. But it places an emphases on those who ask questions that aren't received well.

Comment: @Shog9 if you're watching, there's a lot of pluralization bugs in that message. Not just in the form of S's, but also the grammar of the entire first sentence. :)

Comment: Someone's about to get bludgeoned by a huge "S".

Comment: I long for the day I get a report on that from someone who isn't reading a screenshot, @Mysticial. It'll mean someone who could actually benefit from it took the time to read it carefully.