# How can other users warn a new user, frequently missing the SO policies for 'How to ask here?'

Tags: discussion, support, new-users

I've come across this [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4106665/user4106665) today, which at first glance looks harmless.

But the user manages to ask the same question again and again

[image]

[Getting error in Karatsuba's multiplication program [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204957/getting-error-in-karatsubas-multiplication-program?noredirect=1#comment41093556_26204957) (+10k visible only)

[image]

[Correction needed in Karatsuba's multiplication algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190878/correction-needed-in-karatsubas-multiplication-algorithm) (+10k visible only)

Well, the OP seems to be unaware that this behavior will lead to a question ban finally, but how could we give them notice of that, if these questions are deleted even quicker than a official close has been applied?

I don't know how to even flag for moderator attention, if there's nothing really left to put a flag on it.

---

> [*@Josh Caswell*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell) "Pretty sure that you can flag a deleted post for moderator attention."

Finally I found, that it's still possible to flag these deleted questions for moderator attention and I did:

[image]

Comment: @Louis No, I didn't consider the profile is _'harmful'_, but the behavior is. It, just will lead the user to be question banned straightaway, without having any chance to warn them.

Comment: From the the questions and their comments I think we can deduce two things. First, the questioner wants a fixed function (as in: code) and only that, not directions towards one. Second, the questioner seems to want to hide their activity here (the problem is most probably homework). I say let the ban hammer fall, as I'm not confident at all the questioner would listen to anything we may throw their way.

Comment: @Louis That appears to be minor here. I meant the user's profile looks just _harmless_ at a 1st glance, as having no _asked questions_, or _answered questions_ and no rep changes publicly visible. Though the victims of the _deja vú_ will well know that user tries to undergo the _'close vote queue'_ radar. I don't know how to even flag for moderator attention, if there's nothing really left to put a flag on it.

Comment: @Louis I'll leave my last comment, because it clarifies my concerns. Perhaps I'll edit my question to add this info.

Comment: Frankly, I think the user is doing us a favor by deleting these. While somebody took the time to give an answer on one of them, I don't find it or the questions to be likely to be of use to anyone else. If the answered one was undeleted and I saw it, I'd probably vote to close.

Comment: Pretty sure that you can flag a deleted post for moderator attention.

Comment: @JoshCaswell _"I think the user is doing us a favor ..."_ But not really for themselves, that's what I'm concerned of. Is there a way to warn them, without having moderator powers yourself, or have a pickup point to ask for mod attention?

Comment: Oh, I see. No, there's no way for you to do it that I can think of, although the new [question quality rate-limiter thingadongdong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258757/) should do so.

Comment: @JoshCaswell IMHO your contributions well make up an answer for this question. I'd well accept it, if you would like to consolidate an answer.

Comment: stop babysitting people... why would you want to warn him of his terrible behaviour. Obviously he's on his way to get banned - there will be a hint how to "start over" etc. Were not here to babysit people, or are we?

Comment: @vba4all this! who cares!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

He's already been warned. He's also been told [to wait several days before trying to ask again.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) This happens automatically once the system is able to determine that the person trying to ask a question has a history of asking poorly-received questions.

If he ignores it, he'll be heavily rate-limited and continually warned right up to the point where the system tells him to [go away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

So to answer your question, well... You can leave a comment if you happen to latch on to one of these questions before it gets deleted (looks like you did). But first and foremost, *don't forget to downvote* bad questions: when folks are good about giving it some signal to work with, the system handles a lot of the heavy lifting *automatically*.

Comment: I wouldn't probably leave a comment due to experience of having a comment trigger a words & voting war... stay anonymous.

Comment: Stay anonymous, or utilize self control to not get into a war over it (after all, wars have two participants.  If the guy starts flaming you, you can just flag his comments).  Either way.  Most people in my experience are open to correction, I've only had one person get mad

Comment: @StormeHawke wars don't always have two willing participants, ask Poland...

Comment: @BradWerth This is the internet and there is no territory to be conquered... *slightly* different from real life...

Comment: @StormeHawke not different, in the context of this discussion. If one side wants to "start a war", the other side doesn't really have much say. I have had the same experience of having a comment trigger a words & voting war as vba4all has. Nowadays, an anonymous downvote is comment enough, for me...

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the actionable feature request here is "Deleted questions should be visible to 10K+ users on the asker's profile"?  Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/users/4106665/user4106665 it certainly does appear to be an idle account rather than an account engaged in a pattern of misbehavior.

Comment: That's a not that bad idea! Yes, I've been missing this feature already.

Comment: May be you should post a [tag:feature-request] for this.

Comment: Posted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272958/10k-users-should-be-able-to-see-deleted-questions-and-answers-on-the-posters-pr

Comment: Supported! ....