# 10K users should be able to see deleted questions and answers on the poster's profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, deleted-answers, deleted-questions

Users with 10K rep can see deleted questions and answers if they already have a link, but they are not visible any other way.  In particular, a user with many deleted questions or answers shows no sign of this on their profile page.  This can hinder detection of patterns of misbehavior.

For instance, as discussed at [How can other users warn a new user, frequently missing the SO policies for 'How to ask here?'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272866/) a user, https://stackoverflow.com/users/4106665/user4106665 , repeatedly posted the same bad question, then deleted it again in response to negative comments and downvotes.  If you looked at their profile page, say while one instance of the bad question is active, you'd have no way of knowing they were doing this.

Proposal: 10K+ users should be able to see a list of all deleted questions and answers by a particular user, from that user's profile page.  (Maybe there should only be a count of each on the profile summary tab, which is a link to a full list.)

Comment: I have several problems with this on several levels, although I believe the underlying idea is sound. 10K+ looks too low a barrier to me, and easy access from the profile page ties too much to the user and is too prone to abuse by the Meta Batman Justice Squad Effect IMHO. Ideally this should be anonymized and tied to posts, not users.

Comment: While I understand the reasoning for this feature request, there is way too much room for abuse here.  While the request and the reasoning is noble, there are enough vigilante users at or near 10K that I can see this being abused.  I have 20K on MSE and I absolutely do not want this level of access.  I only care about acting on posts and trying to help within the bounds of the info I have.  Mods should be the only users who can see everything.

Comment: @animuson: why is this [meta-tag:status-declined]? I thought that was something only SE staff could determine?

Comment: @Matt Stack Exchange has already indicated they're not interested in adding deleted posts to those lists for users.

Comment: We're not machines, we're human and every human needs freedom for making mistakes.

Comment: I have reverted your edit to the [tag:C] tag advising it should be used for the oldest version instead of the newer one as it is undergoing meta discussion at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373655/c-tag-usage-radical-changes-to-tag-wiki-which-policy-to-keep . Please visit the meta discussion to leave your opinion of which version it should refer to.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that hard to find deleted questions in google's cache. Viewing the cached item, you can pull the question's link from the URL, which will pull up the closed question in SO.

Example: I recognized [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896771/google-form-with-sendemail-script-converting-numbers-to-scientific#comment49837965_30896771) replicated question.

[image: screenshot]

The OP nicely indicated they'd asked before - but no link to their previous question, and it didn't show up on their profile. Conclusion... it was deleted. (applause)

Since I'd contributed to this one, I googled my ID + OP's ID. You could try the title of the question + the OP's ID, which should also give a short result list.

**All questions by user:** `site:stackoverflow.com` + OP's ID. You still have to hunt & peck to find which ones are deleted - not ideal, but with new users the list tends to be mercifully short.

[image: screenshot]

Open the cached copy, and the [original URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761423/how-to-prevent-google-forms-from-converting-form-input-to-scientific-notation-fo) is shown in the preamble.

[image: screenshot]

Caveat: Long-deleted questions will age out of Google's cache. Eventually.