# C tag usage, radical changes to tag wiki. Which policy to keep?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Previously the tag usage policy for [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) questions was that if no language standard was specified, we assume that the question is about the current ISO standard. As a veteran user, this has been my take on the SO community consensus over the years. Therefore I added this policy to the tag usage three years ago, [edit 65](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607013/65).

Now another user has radically changed the tag usage policy to instead refer to the old, obsolete C90 standard if nothing else is mentioned, [edit 116](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607013/116).

Rather than having some edit war over this, I would like to actually know what is the community consensus among those who follow the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag.

As usual, please use votes to indicate agree/disagree for any answer posted below!

Comment: For now, I reverted to the previous guidance (current C version) as advised by Nicol Bolas, since the new guidance (oldest C version) is at risk of conflicting with usage built up over the years, and linked to this meta discussion in the edit comment. I also pinged @zwol and invited them to come discuss this here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thank you. At this point there appears to be an overwhelming consensus (41 agree, none disagree) to keep the old policy, so if nobody wants to discuss this further, we can leave the wiki as it stands after your rollback. zwol did add some helpful notes about compiling with maximum warnings (though I disagree about using -std=gnuxx which is a Linux-only remark), but we can add such again later. Perhaps under a separate headline "compiler advice" or such.

Comment: I actually did not do a full revert, since there were indeed useful notes and further edits; I instead checked edit 115, and surgically reinstated the previous guidance (as well as removing the new one) while keeping all other edits... or at least trying to.

Comment: @MatthieuM. shouldn't the excerpt also be changed back so it matches with the wiki?

Comment: I did a rollback of the excerpt.

Comment: @KamiKaze: I did not spot any change there :/

Comment: "*Rather than having some edit war over this*" - just roll back any radical change. Only when they edit it again, it's become an edit war and necessary to have a meta discussion.

Comment: Should we go so far as to say something along the lines of "If you are constrained to use a C compiler that does not support either C11 or C18, you should add the appropriate versioned tag — [tag:c90] or [tag:c99]"?  And should the guidance be updated to note that the tag [tag:c17] should be used for the current version since the tag [tag:c18] refers to a specific microprocessor implementation of a C compiler, and it got there first?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Tags are not attributed on a first-come first-serve basis; if C18 is an official C standard, then [tag:c18] has just become ambiguous and a meta discussion should be opened to discuss its fate.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  Yes, it is mostly FCFS. And when I started the discussion a month or so ago, it was substantively ignored.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As discussed then, the `__STDC_VERSION__` is 17 not 18. From there on we should fall in line. The year of publication of ISO standards was always unreliable and fickle, they always lag behind national/continental standard publications.

Answer (score 76):

Unilaterally changing the very meaning of a tag like this is a big no-no. The user in question should not have done it without bringing it up on MSO first, and therefore you should revert it back ASAP. Any discussion can take place *after* the tag wiki has been restored to what it was.

Comment: I fully agree, though as I'm partial, having posted the original policy back in the days, it would be better if this is moderated by someone else with wiki edit privileges (and link to this meta thread).

Answer (score 57):

My proposal is to use the previous policy:

> Unless the question does not explicitly mention which version of the C standard that is used, it is assumed that the current version is used. That is, whichever version of ISO 9899 that ISO currently lists as active.

This makes SO in synch with international standardization. In addition, SO should be a place where we teach modern programming, not obsolete practices from the 1990s.

C is a very old language and so we do frequently encounter books, teachers and programmers with completely outdated knowledge. But teaching 30 year old practices isn't doing anyone a favour in the long term.

Especially since lots of the language changes, particularly in C99, were pure "language bug fixes", such as getting rid of implicit int and non-prototype functions.

Most of the canonical posts about C already on the site assume the current version of the standard, such as for example [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c), [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

The current industry de facto standard appears to be C99, with many converting to C11. Tool coverage of C11 is fairly good nowadays, both among mainstream compilers and embedded systems compilers.

The current standard is C17 (as of April 2018), but it is just C11 + bug fixes, with no new features. It has the very same chapter enumeration as C11.

Comment: AFAIK other language tags use the same unwritten rule, e.g. [c#] or [java] refer to the most recent version, while a tag like [c#-3.0] refers to a specific version. It seems completely backwards to me to have the main tag of a language refer to an old version.

Comment: @Stijn, I think it's not exactly as you said. Using only [c#] would be a "I don't care/know about version". Usually, if asking about newest features the versioned tag is a must (it's often added by experienced users). E.q. some years ago [c#-6.0] was edited into every question about c# 6.0 features. Later c# 7.0 appears and the similar things happen, while **older** questions suddenly stops getting versioned tag. So questions with just [c#] are kind of "it's *usual* c#, nothing special". I am not sure if the same practices are going to be good for [c]..

Comment: Tbh, I don't actually know what [c++] by itself means... I guess I assume latest standard? I'll have to be more conscious next time and think about how I'm answering. I definitely prefer it when people tag questions with, e.g. [c++][c++17]. I find that pretty helpful and unambiguous.

Answer (score 14):

An unversioned tag should refer to any version of language or the latest, amended and fixed version of the language:

- [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), …

A versioned tag on the other hand is to refer to a specific version of the language at the time of the release:

- [c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89), [c99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c99), [c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c11), [c17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c17), […](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=c17+dbz)
- [c#-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0), [c#-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0), [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0), [c#-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0), [c#-6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0), [c#-7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-7.0), [c#-7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-7.1), [c#-7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-7.2), [c#-8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-8.0), …
- [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2), [swift2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.1), [swift2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2), [swift2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.3), [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3), [swift3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3.1), [swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4), [swift4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4.1), [swift4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4.2), …
- [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7), [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8), [java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9), [java-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-10), [java-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-11), …
- …

Comment: Yeah this is how it was before changes. All the C89 -> C17 tags have their tag usage documented as "use this in addition to the C tag in case you have questions about a specific version".

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure that's *quite* how it was before. As I'm reading Cœur's answer, he's saying that an unversioned tag should be taken to be ambiguous about whether it's referring to the latest version of the language or is completely version-agnostic, thus leaving answerers free to answer for the latest version or to chime in with answers about older versions (or even with a full narrative about how the answer has changed across versions) if they want to. FWIW, I generally agree with that approach (although I'm not a C guy and might be missing C-specific reasons not to apply it here).

Comment: @MarkAmery ah, now I see how my first sentence is ambiguous. I meant to emphasize that answers can be for newer versions of the language that were released after the question itself.

Answer (score 6):

First off, I would like to apologize for making a unilateral change without discussion.  I did this because I honestly thought I was correcting a simple error.  I have always answered C questions by starting from C89, and mentioning C99 and/or C11 changes when relevant.  I see many others doing the same.

I do think that "unless stated we assume you are asking about the oldest standardized version of the language" is the correct way to handle a language as old as C, with so much old code floating around, and where an absolute majority of compilers (I would guess) still default to C89.  It might be reasonable to assume that people working on *new* code are working against C99, but not C11 or C17.  Not for another decade at least.  And many of the better questions in the C tag are about code written in the 1990s.

I am also going to refrain from editing the tag wiki until further notice, but regardless of how the community ultimately decides, I would like the factual observation that "C compilers are slow to fully adopt new revisions of the C standard, and many C codebases in common use are still written against old revisions" to be restored.  I would also like the text I wrote about turning on warnings to be restored, as that is independent and sound advice.

To answer certain specific points raised in other posts / comments:

- Cœur: C needs different treatment than most of the languages commonly discussed on SO, because C has more, and more complicated, history.  If we got lots of questions about FORTRAN or COBOL, it would probably also be inappropriate to assume the latest revision of the relevant standards for them.
- user694733: Yes, a minority of commenters on questions do insist that C is only C17, but that is the wrong way to handle C, and we should not stick to an incorrect policy just because it's been there for a long time.
- lundin: Of course we should *teach* people about the newer versions of the standard. The change I want to see in community practice is I want us to stop *assuming that people are using the newest version* when they haven't told us they are.  Assuming C99 is much less of a problem than assuming C11, since, as you say, C99 was mostly bugfixes and adoptions of common extensions; if we were to settle on "we assume C99 unless stated otherwise, as this rev is the most commonly used nowadays, but be aware that your compiler still might be defaulting to the older C89" I could live with that.

  I would also like to see an end to pedantically true but practically false and pedagogically counterproductive statements like "implicit int has been removed from the language"; as you know, almost all compilers continue to support this, even in their "strict conformance" modes, as an extension, which means people will observe that it still works and assume that means you don't know what you're talking about and discount *all* of your advice.
- lundin: I understand why you want to tell people to use the strictest possible conformance mode for new code, but `-std=cXX` can and will break system headers on *any* operating system; recent versions of GNU libc are actually the *least* likely to have trouble (because they put in a bunch of time fixing these bugs).  The errors you get tend to be things like "unknown type name `u_int32_t`" pointing at a header you didn't even know you were dragging in.  For the kinds of questions we tend to get from people with not a lot of experience with the language, I think that will be a distraction, and discourage them from turning on the warnings that will actually find problems with their own code.

---

I don't have the time or the patience to get into a long discussion on meta about this.  I will respond to direct questions, but not till tomorrow: I have a deadline on the dayjob and I've already spent as much time as I can afford to spend on SO today just writing this post.

Comment: The mainstream compilers default to C11 since many years. As do the majority of embedded systems compilers. gcc switched default early 2015.

Comment: Regarding implicit int, no common compiler has used that for a vast number of years. Which is why the whole "do I cast the result of malloc" debate that always pops up on SO has turned into a non-issue. In order to get implicit int, you have to go and tell the compiler explicitly to compile as C90. The only reason for that being maintaining old stuff.

Comment: Regarding `-std=cxx -pedantic`, newbies should be using it so that they learn actual standard C, and not about some obscure non-standard gnu that's only used by the Linux kernel and no one else. We very frequently get questions from beginners who are confused _because_ of gnu C, I had that just a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067353/why-is-this-statement-producing-a-linker-error-with-gcc). It is old, non-standard stuff that isn't used outside Linux, causing more harm than good.

Comment: You are late to the party, so the initial wave of voters is gone. I think this will distort the votes on this topic, making it not an optimal evaluation metric. My personal preference would also be default to C99, as I feel it is the most common (at the time).

Comment: @KamiKaze The initial wave had the option to down vote the answer I posted if they didn't agree. As for C99 I think it would be an odd default. 5 years ago I would have agreed, but all compilers worth mentioning are done with the transition to C11. It's just Microsoft lagging behind, while small-time embedded systems compilers have managed it.

Comment: @Lundin You made very convincing arguments and I would be very hard pressed to disagree (downvote) with you especially as the rest of the answers are also in your favor. So the option would be more like agree or do nothing. Also we do not know how many of the voters really care for [c] and were just convinced by your good reasoning. (A moot point I know, but I just want the best outcome from this, so I raised some concerns). If we get a good portion of total votes here my concern is not valid.

Comment: @Lundin  I also agree that C99 is an odd default but the last project I was involved with explicitly used C99. I am not talking about compiler support but a possible industry "support" ( I just have small knowledge about the spread in the industry, so this is just anecdotical). I am not really decided on the issue, just want the best possible outcome.

Comment: Thanks for coming; I didn't intend to revert any warning guidance, so that's on me, I agree it's good advice. I maintain a large collection of C++ answers, and my modus operandi there in case of change of behavior or idioms across versions has been to (1) split the answer in parts, one for each group of versions and (2) start by the most modern. For example, here is [an edit revision from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4478247/revisions) on an 8 years old answer of mine. Would you find this kind of layout to be a good option for C answers?

Comment: I agree that there {sh,c}ould be warning about the slowness of compilers, particularly those for embedded systems, to keep up to date with the standard. I tend towards the view that for a year or two after the release of a new version of the standard, the previous version is the most relevant version — I will continue to cite C11 for a while for a variety of reasons (online HTML version available, C18 standard is too damn expensive to buy, inertia, …), but the differences between C11 and C18 are small.  When relevant, I work backwards to older standards; I start with the recent and work older.

Comment: I see plenty of people discussing multiple C versions when they answer questions tagged [c] but not with a specific C version, but I have never perceived a widely held position that such questions should be interpreted as being specifically about C89.  On the contrary, the perceived consensus Lundin describes in the question is consistent with my own perception.  I think it appropriate that the more general tagging attract broader commentary, but that's a different issue from what unqualified "C" should be interpreted to mean in that context.

Answer (score 3):

One additional thing to consider is that a lot of comments have been added all these years bringing up previous policy. The change invalidated all these comments, creating a lot of conflicting information.

While decision should not be done based on content of these comments alone, it does support the idea of restoring the old policy back.