# Does a post-ban get lifted after serial downvotes have been reversed?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, post-ban, serial-voting

I noticed someone intentionally downvoted a few of my questions. I lost about 16 reputation points, and now I am banned from asking questions.

[image: Screenshot of reputation changes]

Now that I got my reputation back, can I get the ban lifted?

Comment: Did you also delete some downvoted questions recently?

Comment: Just a couple of ones that had no reply or comments I would not think that you would get banned for deleting some of own questions.

Comment: "+16 Voting corrected" - that should not have an influence on a ban. Did you click "(learn more)"?

Comment: OK Yes it is the first time that happened to me.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 _"I would not think that you would get banned for deleting some of own questions."_ Deleted questions still count for the ban.

Comment: Ok Thanks everyone, don't like that idea. Should not get banned for deleting unanswered questions

Comment: A moderator ought to take pity on you and unban you again.  If none show up then use a custom flag on one of your post and direct them to this question.  Give it a day or two, it is the weekend.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have no control over question or answer bans. They are applied and enforced by the system. That said, I do see that your question ban was lifted three hours ago after the votes were invalidated. The user responsible has been dealt with.

Comment: I personally think that the post ban is the most horrible idea in the history of the universe. Seriously, a major problem on this site is duplicate questions/answers, off-topic, so on and so forth and we're actively encouraged to hunt these down and correct them. Yet, when we do it to ourselves, we get flagged for banning. I've had the site warn me I was on my way to a ban for self correcting. I've never in my life been punished for self correcting by anyone or anything but stack exchange.

Comment: IMHO such ban should not exist anymore. The idea of the site is to provide a knowledge base. A user self-correcting should not be an issue of any type to deal with. A user self-correcting is even more useful than a user correcting others.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire ranting in a comment on a post is not a way to effect change.  If you want to change the system, then come up with a replacement and back it up with facts and stats and an objective argument.  Because the site has a question quality problem (too many low quality posts), my experience tells me the community seems to agree with the premise of the post-ban as a way to throw a roadblock at users who habitually post low quality content, so removing it isn't an option, but that doesn't mean it couldn't be replaced.

Comment: Also given that the problem persists and manual intervention is almost always required (by mods and close votes), it's evident that users who post low quality stuff don't self correct, so in light of this, writing an algorithm to catch such users that heavily factors in that target for ban self-corrects just seems all the more abhorrently stupid in light of these truths. Thanks for teaching me how to think.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli You're absolutely correct. It's 100% pure backwards logic to target a self-correcting user as a contributor to the problem of persistent low quality posts.

Comment: I can ask questions again I have been trying my best to help other users, because I have learned so much on here.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire - The vote-related question ban is, in my observations, the only thing keeping this site from completely falling apart. It has been one of the only effective means of slowing the deluge of absolute trash facing this site every day. Tens of thousands of the worst possible questions are blocked by this, and it helps keep out the most abusive users of the site. Can this sometimes catch innocent people? Yes, but we try to help in those relatively rare cases (like here). Were all of the question-banned users allowed to post today, we'd immediately be overrun by trash.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The post ban is automatic and is not keyed to any 1 specific event (or series of events in the case of serial downvoting/downvoting reversal).

While Stack Exchange has never made the exact algorithm public, there are enough clues to have a general idea how it works.  This is probably an oversimplification but think of this way.... you have a "quality score" and there is a specific threshold.  If your score drops below that threshold, you are banned.  When you score rises above the threshold, you are unbanned.

**So could you get banned after someone serial downvoted you?**

Yes, it is known that votes are a key component in any ban calculations, so if you received downvotes (serial or not), it could have caused you to get banned.

**Would my ban get removed when the serial voting script removes the votes?**

Not necessarily and depends on other factors.  Taken on their own, the removed serial votes no longer exist so they shouldn't even be considered by the ban algorithm.  Given that, if nothing else happened, the ban should be lifted when the serial voting script runs.

But if you got banned as a direct result of 8 downvotes, that means you were close enough to the ban threshold that other actions could come into play.

You mentioned you [deleted some posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290658/does-post-ban-get-lifted-after-serial-downvotes-have-been-reversed#comment178730_290658), so that could be part of the issue.

Deleted posts do have an influence on your banned status.  They count the same way as regular undeleted posts count, so deleting negatively scored posts will not improve your ban situation, and there appears to be other components of the algorithm that may be changed (indirectly) when you delete a post (whether the post itself has positive, negative, or neutral influence), so you could have unintentionally caused yourself to get banned when you deleted those posts.

The fix may simply be to undelete those posts you deleted recently as see what happens.  It ***may*** solve your immediate problem (no promises on that).

But it certainly won't solve the question-ban issue completely.  You have found that you are close to the question-ban threshold, so you should focus on trying to get yourself a little further away from that ban threshold so you won't get banned again by a couple of downvotes or post deletions.

I don't see anything significantly negative in your profile that would appear to be a major factor in a question ban, but that could simply mean you have an older (deleted) post with a lot of downvotes.  But you also have a lot of questions with a net zero score (and most probably have no votes at all).  Trying to get upvotes on any of your questions, by improving them, may help.

Comment: Thanks for for explaining it now understand.

Comment: Good points. "I don't see anything significantly negative in your profile" - then we can all agree now that the system that's harming this law-abiding and contributing member to this community is fundamentally broken because it is discouraging and potentially pushing away good, contributing members of our community. We're apparently a community of programming experts who aren't capable of programming half decent algorithms.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire both question and answer refer deleted posts - without learning more about these it would be too early to jump at conclusions

Comment: @gnat I'm not jumping to conclusions I'm speaking out of my own experience with this flawed system. Even when I was already at a 4-5 thousand rep, I posted and deleted a couple of questions after deciding that they were too localized or finding that there was already an answer I missed. The next time I went to post a question I got big bold warnings that I better make sure my question isn't garbage because I'm on the verge of getting a post ban. Automatically trusted on any new SE site, top %5 overall but hey, I might just be a low quality spammer.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire you are talking about [ban warning](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258757/839601), it's not the same as actual ban

Comment: @TechnikEmpire So, you asked some low-quality questions (you yourself even thought they were low-quality since you deleted them) and the next time you were going to ask a question the system told you: "Hey, if you're going to ask a question, make it a good one". What's the big problem? If deleted question do not count toward a question ban, a user could just delete all his previous questions whenever he gets banned (or when he gets a warning he is in danger of getting banned) and happily continue posting bad questions.

Comment: I got a downvote on a completely relevant answer to a question http://serverfault.com/a/723826/246507 . This problem will persist if someone like myself cannot at least make an anonymous request to the downvoter to reevaluate their downvote. I don't have to know who the person is, but this feature would move in a direction to help remedy this issue. .. sending a message like "Hi, I just made my answer/question better (or corrected an issue), please consider reversing your downvote. Thanks!"

Comment: @RussellEGlaue that is completely unrelated to the answer here or the question.  The question here was do serial downvotes affect your ban status.  If you have a feature you want to propose, then feel free to propose it, but I suggest you search first and make sure no one has proposed it before [hint: [it has](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c)]

Comment: @psubee you are correct. The way I worded the comment suggests your interpretation. Please let me be clearer - my intention was that we do not necessarily know who the serial downvoter is, and we currently have no way to communicate with that person to resolve the issue they have with us. I am only suggesting that this feature could help in that regard.

Comment: @RussellEGlaue No, I understand your intent.  But my point is complaining about a feature (or lack-there-of) in a comment to an answer to a barely related question doesn't really accomplish much.  If you want to make your point heard, you need to propose a new feature or advocate for the implementation of it by answering an existing feature request.