# Score needed to lift post ban

Tags: support, reputation, post-ban

So, a year or more ago, I think. I was post banned. Today I decided to change that. I went on an answering spree and earned 210 points. I suppose this is a lot for a guy with a score like mine. Now, I know what post banned means. I just want to ask if the formula for automatically lifting post bans is publicly disclosed.

Comment: No, it is not publicly disclosed.

Comment: Thak you. Do you maybe have a estimate? Nevermind if you dont.

Comment: I think [this answer sums it up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290668/578411). Don't expect anything to be revealed about how it exactly works, it is a trade secret to prevent users trying to game the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user0001 pointed out in the comments, this is not disclosed.

The reason that it is not disclosed, is to prevent people from gaming the system; doing just enough to get the ban lifted, or being just good enough to stay on the good side of a ban.

From [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

> If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

As you have earned 210 points, though, I think you are on your way. If your answers aren't downvoted or flagged, you must be on your way to get your ban lifted. Good luck!

Comment: Don't forget that deleted questions count as well. The OP might ask for links to the deleted ones to see if they can be salvaged.

Comment: I got my deleted questions undeleted. But can anyone(if you are a mod, not you guy I know mods have diamonds ;)) check if I got anymore deleted questions?

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić last two negatively voted deleted questions are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595616/selling-play-store-apps-from-non-checkout-countries) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415620/making-program-extensions)

Comment: Thank You, but I thibk I will just need to earn enough rep to overcome that. Although the first question is simply bad, I think the second question is nicely formed, and the answer would be Reflection.

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić Users with 10k points or more should be able to see deleted posts. I have only glanced at the second question that Jon Clements linked, but (having over 3k points) I can see that people are voting to reopen it. Looks like things are going well.

Comment: Well 'EDIT: e.g. Currently I have the possibility to send popups to another PC' does not sound like the kind of question I would vote up or for reopen.  It's more like a kind of malware functionality that I would down/close/delete vote.  The first question is business/marketing and so just totally bad:(