# What to do if you are banned from asking a question on that day because of serial downvoting?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, post-ban, serial-voting

Well, I was a victim of serial downvoting on 18th February 2016, as you see below:

[image]

I was also returned the reputation as you can see

[image]

Well, but on the same day, I was again serial downvoted:

[image]

I knew that it will again be reversed by the script that runs at 3:00 UTC, and did not worry about it. After some time, when I went to ask a question, I was surprised to see that I was banned from asking. I had once just received a warning once when I was trying to delete a question and once on the asking page when I had asked two to three poor questions. Recently, in the days I had never even received a warning message, and till yesterday, I was not banned. Suddenly it struck me that those serial downvotes on my questions for two days might have caused the ban, and knew that I could not ask a question till the next day. I knew that those downvotes could not themselves occur a ban, but they might have added on my poor questions and raised a ban.

Now I was urgent to ask my question, and could not understand what to do. I felt that this was wrong, as I should have not received the ban from asking because of those serial downvotes.

So can someone tell me a way to ask a question today?

**EDIT:**

I was serial downvoted again. Some of them were the ones mentioned in my third pic already, but you can see that again I got downvoted on many of my questions:

[image]

Some questions were downvoted which were not downvoted earlier, and some questions were downvoted again.

**NOTE:** This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290658/does-a-post-ban-get-lifted-after-serial-downvotes-have-been-reversed) as I am not asking about the bans being lifted after the reversal of serial downvotes but what to do if you are banned on that day because of serial downvotes.

Comment: Related: [Does a post-ban get lifted after serial downvotes have been reversed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290658/does-a-post-ban-get-lifted-after-serial-downvotes-have-been-reversed)

Comment: Well, the serial downvoting might not be the only reason. At least *half* of your questions have been downvoted several times, beyond those downvotes you have shown in the screenshot above. You may need to consider that there is a systemic quality problem with your questions. I'll observe, in case you haven't already made this observation for yourself, that excessively basic questions are not particularly well-received in the C and C++ communities.

Comment: @CodeGray and I quote *"Now I was urgent to ask my question"*. Cause and effect?

Comment: @CodyGray, yes that is why I have mentioned that I had a lot of poor quality and few deleted questions, and I was close to get a ban. But I had not got it. The serial downvotes triggered the ban.

Comment: Holy cow, you have asked a question tagged both `[c]` and `[c++]`, and outright said it was an okay use of these tags, and you *survived*? Not a small feat.

Comment: Looking at some of your upvoted questions, even those (2 I looked at) are not very good. Im not going to DV you now because bringing it up on meta is at least showing some spine, but _damn_.

Comment: I suggest you take a read of the [ask] and the [help] and rework some of your questions to make them better. Then they'll get upvoted and your ban will be lifted.

Comment: FYI for your edit.... that is not serial downvoting, it is just the Meta Effect at work.  This question brought some extra attention to your questions and people are voting on the questions.

Comment: Thats what I meant with posting on meta takes some spine. Meta is like a magnifying glass, if your questions/answers are truly good and you bring them up, you'll get lots of upvoted. Conversely, the same happens with bad q/a and downvotes.

Comment: Note that *"urgent to ask my question"* is a bit of a red flag; this isn't a helpdesk.

Comment: Considering you were serially downvoted on three separate occasions, it might be worth flagging one of your own serially-downvoted posts for moderator attention asking them to escalate to a community manager so they can take action against the user doing this. Usually they'd just let the system work, but this person is persistent enough that it's actively hampering your ability to participate on the site.

Comment: I looked at your questions, at least 75% of them deserve aggressive downvotes because they are just duplicate or basic noise questions. Now that you have complained on meta, you have put a spot light on yourself. **you are asking crap questions and creating noise in a tag that is populated by extremely sophisticated users, they are going to punish you for it.** that is just how it is. Putting that you started C programming in the 5th grade and you are asking basic beginner questions like this right now, I expect you to be in the 5th grade. Doesn't sound like that is the case. Good luck.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To address your actual question of what to do....  in the end there is very little that can be done.  If the votes were indeed serial, then they will be reversed at 3am UTC as you are already aware.

The only way to get them reversed sooner is for a Stack Overflow employee to actually manually reverse the serial votes.  I can't speak for them, but it is certainly plausible that they would do so if your contact them explain the situation.  However after [contacting them via email](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), it can take several days for them to get back to you due to volume of incoming emails, which by then it will be too late.  There's really not much you can do to expect immediate service.

So the best advice is to sit back and wait it out.

One additional suggestion (based on [Brad Larson's input](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317262/what-to-do-if-you-are-banned-from-asking-a-question-on-that-day-because-of-seria#comment310931_317265)) is if you are a victim of multiple serial voting sprees (especially in a very short time window) is to raise a custom flag on one of your posts to explain that you have been serial voted multiple times.  While the moderator's can't do much (directly) to help with the downvoting issues, they have a direct line of communication to the community team (even this is not necessarily going to be a fast process as the moderator flag queue can get large and there is no guarantees they will get to your flag immediately).

They also have tools to see patterns in voting (but not see the votes directly).  They will be able to tell if your downvoter is the same person both times and address the situation directly with that voter to help prevent it from happening a 3rd time.

---

But to address the underlying cause, you should never be that desperate to ask a question that you ***need*** to ask it today, at least in my opinion.  Take the opportunity to do some additional research on your problem, and take the time to work on the question so you know it is clear and answerable and contains all of the key elements of a good question, so that if/when the post ban is lifted, you will be able to ask a well received question.

The fact that a few serial downvotes pushed you into the question ban (twice in 3 days) means you are very close to the ban.  The ban is just a symptom of the main problem that you probably need to spend more time working on your question asking skills.  If you keep going at the current rate, you are just going to trigger the ban yourself (without serial voting to help you) and it will be very difficult to recover from.

I suggest you take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  There is some very good advice in that help center article as well as some links to external sites that may also help you with your question asking skills.

Comment: I've already notified the SE community team about this, as this user was being targeted by a repeat serial downvoter. I've also warned the user responsible, as this is not their first time doing this. Beyond contacting the SE team, if you're the subject of repeat serial downvotes it might be worth a flag just to let moderators know that we may need to have a word with someone.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks.  I'll work in the flag part for repeat serial voting since that seems very relevant to handling it

Comment: @psubsee2003, thanks, your answer clears everything. Also, I had already raised a flag to tell the moderators about the serial downvoting. Although it is pending. Anyway, those serial downvotes got reversed, and that flag is of no use anymore.

Comment: @BradLarson, yup, I'll surely do that next time if I suspect being serial downvoted again.

Answer (score 14):

So I ran through [your question list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5735775/ashish-ahuja?tab=questions) and half of your questions are negative scores (indeed, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703395/why-do-most-c-statements-end-with-a-semicolon) probably needs to be closed as opinion). Adding your scores up, you have a **+9 in votes** (not reputation points). Given the negative scores, you may already have some closed questions that were deleted by the roomba cleanup script. So, given all these things, it's not hard to see why a serial downvote pushed you into a ban.

Given the [criteria for banning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) (I hope you've read that thread) what I would do, if I were you, is be on my best behavior to get some more positive reputation (which isn't hard). You're already on that path (a +17 question is a good thing), you just need to be more careful in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure "what purpose does the semicolon serve in C" is actually opinion-based, but I was pretty convinced it had to be a duplicate. Couldn't find one though after a few minutes of searching. Maybe someone else has better Google-fu?

Comment: I did find a semi cross site dupe @CodyGray: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139482/why-are-statements-in-many-programming-languages-terminated-by-semicolons

Comment: Unfortunately, not even Mjölnir will let me close a question as a duplicate of one on another site.

Comment: Yeah.  Just figured I would point it out.

Comment: @CodyGray I just read through the answer and the OP links to that question and the answer is in his answer.  I am going to edit that answer to make it obvious the OP is quoting from the links.

Answer (score 11):

One way to prevent this happening is to only base a post-ban on votes at least one day old. That way, it's based on votes known not to be serial down-voting.

Comment: That actually sounds like a good idea

Comment: Very interesting suggestion. But is it really worth it? We have to keep in mind what has already been said: if you get a post-ban because of voting fraud you already were very close to getting one anyway. Its not so much a "problem" as in you seeing your pending fate a little sooner than you should.