# Question by a not-so-professional developer or a beginner

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues

I am big fan of the Stack Exchange community and mostly use Stack Overflow and [the GIS Stack Exchange site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

I think at least more than half of the developers around this world use Stack Exchange for their questions and over the past 3-4 years Stack Exchange has affected the life of developers in a good way, but look at this side of the forum that all developers are not on par with the website moderator on level of skills such as English, asking a question, technical level, etc.

In my case I must have asked some question with some improper question or duplicate question, so I am stated getting this warning I might be blocked for future questions.

Thing is the question whether it is small or big, we should be treat as same. Everyone should be treated as one, the environment should be agile and should not discourage by blocking them.

I can see Stack Exchange has moved to a new level, but at same time it should not overlook those who are not on par with other users.

Comment: 1. Paragraphs are your friend. 2. We don't expect *perfect* English, but you need to know enough to get your point across, or we won't understand your point. 3. Not blocking people who continue to ask bad questions, even when there's lots of resources out there about [ask]... what's the benefit of that?

Comment: Don't look at it like discouragement by blocking; instead look at the warning as encouragement to improve.

Comment: *Thing is the question whether it is small or big, we should be treat as same*
--
We don't block people for asking *how do I compare Strings in Java* or *how to add 2 numbers*. We block people for *consistently* posting bad questions / answers. This is necessary to prevent low quality posts. Oh and another thing, on SO, we always stress on *voting for the post* instead of *the person who posted it*

Comment: We practice extended quality control here. If you consistently ask only bad question, you as a user are not an asset to the site and the site will consequently remove your ability to ask.

Comment: @ɥɔsıbɐɯ -It is ok if someone is not an *asset* to the community. In fact it is OK to have a person who has not posted a single question, answer or vote.  We don't like people who directly or indirectly degrade the quality of SO.

Comment: @TheLostMind I could have worded that better, yes. My point is that if your questions add no value but instead only clutter the site, the site won't tolerate that forever.

Comment: Let me ask you: *Why are you such a big fan of the SE sites*? There is also reddit and Quora, to name a few. What is the difference that sets this community apart? Might the fact that we actually block/moderate low quality posts be the reason we have such a large fan-base? Shouldn't you step up your effort a bit instead of us lowering our quality bar that made you a fan in the first place?

Comment: duplicate of [How can I understand why am I receiving a warning that I could be blocked?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked)

Answer (score 13):

> but look at this side of the forum that all developers are not on par
>   with the website moderator on level of skills such as English

We do not expect perfect English grammar or punctuation, or even spelling. We do however expect that you put forth an effort to make your post correct and presentable, it's not that hard. If you really cannot spell proper English then have someone else copy-edit your Q before posting, or don't post at all.

> In my case I must have asked some question with some improper question
>   or duplicate question so I am stated getting this warning I might be
>   blocked for future questions.

That's an automated warning. When users ask too many negatively received questions (downvoted, closed, deleted, etc.), they will be blocked from asking further questions until they fix their existing ones. This is an important mechanism of quality control, which is what sets SE apart from other QA sites.

> Thing is the question whether it is small or big, we should be treat
>   as same.

Absolutely not, there are bad and good questions. What a good question should contain is outlined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). **You are expected to read and adhere to the rules laid out in the help center before asking a question on this community.**

> Everyone should be treated as one the environment should be agile and
>   should not discourage by blocking them.

The goal of this site is to build a great repository of questions and answers, not to allow everybody to ask whatever. Just asserting this will not make it true.