# How to ask a duplicate question if the answers are not valid for me?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Note : Even **this question is also like a duplicate question**, but there is no answer for my question so I had to ask this question. I am sorry. I don't know that what is the solution without asking this question.

I need to ask [How can I understand why am I receiving a warning that I could be blocked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked).

This is the answer for it : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258761/7978484

But it is not a answer for me because I just have 1 down vote and I have not delete any question recently.

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking do exactly what you did right now: Link to the duplicate and explain why the answers to that question don't work for you (and make sure they really don't).

Comment: It's not only _recent deleted_  questions that count for the ban IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think I have deleted also just one question. Just one question and just one down vote give this type of warning when I asked more than 10 questions?

Comment: Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/7978484

Comment: The key point in Shog's answer here is: *If you don't think your history looks concerning, then feel free to ignore the warning... Just know that it's a lot harder to lift the ban after you've hit it than it is to avoid it beforehand.* So right now, you probably don't want to get overly concerned about deleted questions, but see if you can't make your zero scored questions better and make sure any further questions are the best you can ask - see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also it's not just questions **you** deleted that count. There are various other ways your questions could be deleted - negatively voted and abandoned, deleted by high rep users or moderators.

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to improve anything, but Jon does hit on a point; that list of zero-voted questions you have likely counts into the reason why you get this neutral suggestion. It only takes one downvote from someone at this point to put any of those questions into troublesome territory. That does not imply they will be downvoted - heck you may receive a upvote or two given enough time, so there is no reason to obsess about it. Just give them a casual glance and see if there aren't any in there that you perhaps did not give enough time.

Comment: `I just have 1 down vote and I have not delete any question recently.`  That doesn't in any way change Shog's answer to the question.  Your question is no different from the duplicate, and has the same answer.