# Making my questions better

Tags: discussion, specific-question, post-ban

For a while I had been banned out from making new questions, but today I checked and now I have been re-enabled in the system, but I'm worried about doing something against rules that might lock me out once again.

Right now, when I press the "Ask Question" button, I receive the following hint/warning:

[image]

While I was blocked I tried to improve all my questions as far as I could, correcting typos, grammar, awarding answers, etc. But I guess there might be still some more room for improvement, but I'm in need of pointers in that way, so: could anyone please assist me on such? Hopefully, based on my current questions and, not just on general site rules, as I've already tried following all of them.

Regards, to whoever would read and/or help me!

Edit...I just got this suggestion for THIS question:

[image]

But the provided link was exactly what I used to improve my older questions, so I guess is not where I should look at right now, as I hope I got all those issues already covered.

This seems to be my worst question:

[Monitoring Tomcat processes CPU spikes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556276/monitoring-tomcat-processes-cpu-spikes)

As it has a "-1" in votes. I've even added new info right now to try making it even better, as the received answer and the comments do provide hints on workarounds of the asked question, but not an exact answer on what I'd like to do, perhaps there's just no way to it, but that might also be a possible answer, couldn't it?

Comment: So how it works is that there is a threshold for ban that is checked ever time you ask a question. You get a "no" when you are banned. If you are CLOSE to the threshold you get this warning. I would assume that you got out of the ban but are still close to the threshold. Also, just a heads up: just like on the main site, SUPER generic questions don't work.... don't ask "hey meta! go through all my questions on my profile and suggest me improvements". Try to specify it to "I have this question, I edited this in, and it's still not great. What else can I do?".

Comment: Good tip about still being close to the threshold sounds useful...about being too broad on asking for help, I guess I'll to narrow it down....somehow

Comment: basically... don't make the mistake of asking an off topic or poorly researched question. If your next question isn't positively received, you'll likely end up right back in the ban.

Comment: @gvasquez my suggestion would be to look at a question you edited a lot, that you feel is good at this point, and that is somehow not receiving the upvotes you feel it should get. Ask a very specific question on meta "how do I improve THIS question". Explain what you did to improve that question.  As kevin is saying, if you make your next question count, and get a decent reception on it, it may be enough to keep you away from the warning AND the ban. Just take your time :). I like to keep questions for a couple of days as a draft as I work on them. By the time I post it, it's a good Q.

Comment: Good one @Patrice keeping questions as Draft, but sometimes anxiety might work bad on that ;) I was also planning to delete some bad and quite old questions (that I don't really remember the subject of them), but as I've already been provided with answers for them, I'm not allowed to delete them.

Comment: We really don't have general advice for you except what's outlined in the duplicate.  If you have a specific question you want to talk about, then add a link here and ask us about it.

Comment: ok @Makoto let's try using a sample question, to see on possible tips for improving it

Comment: Note that accepting answers has nothing to do with this.  Your question is no better if you accept an answer than if you don't.  You should accept an answer if you get an answer that solves your problem, and not otherwise.  Additionally, while editing the spelling/grammar of your question is great, and you certainly should do it, it's pretty far down on the list of important things your question needs to do.  By all means, ensure the spelling and grammar is good, but not at the expense of including the needed information, having a good scope, a clear question, etc.

Comment: @Makoto i've just added the sample question above

Comment: @Patrice edited this question to include reference to my worst question

Comment: Okay.  If you only want to talk about *this* question, please edit your current question to be focused in scope only to that.  I'd do it but I'm afraid I'd step on your toes a bit.

Comment: That example question is off-topic as it seems to ask for a tool. What you should have done instead (now a bit too late) is add how you enabled dynatrace, what its results look like/ how it helped a bit and what your missing in that setup while you state to be open for other tools. Answers would then suggest a fix for your dynatrace setup or offer better tools.

Comment: see [How can I understand why am I receiving a warning that I could be blocked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258757/839601)

Comment: Asking questions in SO is almost an expertise. And the community is often unhelpfull. I looked at your questions, and I found one that was vague,  general, like "Monitoring Tomcat processes CPU spikes [on hold]"... questions like "is there any", or "how would you" are against the SO rules. What confuses me, is I only found that one (I can see deleted questions), so I can't see why you would have been suspended...

Comment: @gvasquez looking at your profile, I can see a couple of upvoted questions and a single downvoted one (the one in your question) - you don't get banned for that. It seems very likely, that you have a couple of deleted, heavily downvoted questions - you should avoid the mistakes you made asking them.

Comment: Duh....just by pointing at my "bad" question, even more people downvoted it, so I'm now back again in the "banned world" where I can no longer ask questions...lesson: trying to learn leads you to banishment :(

Answer (score 3):

Your linked question ([Monitoring Tomcat processes CPU spikes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556276/monitoring-tomcat-processes-cpu-spikes)) is off-topic.

- It is off-topic because it is a resource request. According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

You could try to salvage the question by locating a specific code routine that is taking an inordinate amount of time and asking for specific information on how to improve its efficiency without specifically asking for a tool. If someone answering recommends a tool, so be it.

You might also ask instead about how to monitor Java and/or Tomcat performance and/or diagnose performance issues without specifically indicating that you want a *tool* to do that, but some people might consider that *too broad* or ask you for code anyway (and downvote you more for not providing it).

Comment: _"some people might consider that too broad"_ I'd say _most_ people do, although that depends on the question at hand, and an answer might still slip through the close votes.