# How much I can ask before blocking to the questions limit

Tags: discussion, questions, post-ban, rate-limiting

I am getting warning from Stack Overflow is that-

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

I am using Stack Overflow almost everyday and ask questions when I need. Now I am getting the warning of blocking.

So I want to know how much question a user can ask before blocking?

Comment: It's not about how many questions you can ask. It's about how many **not well received** questions you can ask. The details about the blocking algorithm are not public though. From your question history I wouldn't have expected you to be close to a ban (unless you have some negative scoring deleted questions).

Comment: Everything you need to know is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @BDL thanks for responding Sir...Sir I have one negative question review that means I am not close enough to get blocking

Comment: @V_rohit depends on how negative the deleted question was

Comment: @WhatsThePoint..means sir It also checked my past deleted negative questions?

Comment: @V_rohit: Yes, it also checks all your deleted posts.

Comment: This is not a healthy attitude to have in response to an imminent block. You should not be afraid of asking questions, but at the same time you should be considering how you can ask better questions to avoid being blocked, not counting how many you have left.

Comment: @V_rohit this is all answered [in the link posted by rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370080/how-much-i-can-ask-before-blocking-to-the-questions-limit#comment603356_370080). Please read it.

Comment: @BDL....Okay Sir I understand

Comment: @BoltClock....I know Sir i did mistakes when I start using SO but now I know a little to use SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022115/navigation-bar-not-showing-title-in-swift-4 if you see my this question I try to explain everything what is the problem ask the question step wise step but still i get a downvote. Why?

Comment: Just to be clear, @V_rohit, downvotes on Meta are separate. They will not affect your status on the main Stack Overflow site.

Comment: At first glance, your questions don't look that bad. You may want to look if you can improve them. FWIW Jon Skeet once wrote an article about [Writing the Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints). It may be useful to you.

Comment: @S.L.Barth....thanks for explaining sir I will keep that in mind in future...but getting downvotes create negative impact and fear in the mind of newbies not to ask questions here

Answer (score 5):

That's up to you, really.

The warning isn't a *formal* question ban, but it means you're on the cusp of one.  The reason for this is that your past questions haven't fared so well on the site - either they were  heavily downvoted or they were flagged by the internal system as "low quality". If you deleted any of your questions, **they still count against you**, and it becomes that much harder to fix those questions.

This should serve as a gigantic alarm telling you that we're *serious* about question quality here and that you should invest copious amounts of time into getting your question clear and concise for the site.  Don't be afraid to ask for feedback of your questions here on Meta, since we have the [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag to discuss such questions.

Comment: But Sir if someone is giving me downvote without explaining the problem then what should I do ? I try everything to put what i did.. For some questions i get an upvote for the same effort

Comment: @V_rohit A single downvote isn't going to do much for the post ban; it just pushes you a little bit closer.  The warning means you're very close to the ban, which means you probably have deleted questions, and those are contributing heavily to pushing you into the ban.  Again, please read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @fbueckert:  [This is a far better reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258757/1079354).

Comment: @Makoto Most of the value that relates to this would be in the comments about deleted content.  Unfortunately, Shog's answer doesn't address that, so I'm not sure how useful that'd be.  That said, it wouldn't hurt to read and absorb them both.

Comment: @fbueckert...Sir I don't see my deleted questions after 60 days in which situation what should I do.. i get 1 downvote in my all 11 questions but still i am getting the warning

Comment: @V_rohit:  Perhaps a fly-by-night moderator will happen upon this question and enlighten you?

Comment: @Makoto....means Sir?