# How can I ask a "good question" and not get flagged?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, question-quality

I am trying my best to ask my questions in a format that is acceptable on this platform. I've used the wizard and searched extensively for documentation that gives direction. However, I keep getting the warning below.

> **"Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more."**

In addition, I have had some users modify my questions to make it "better". One of the things I notice in their modifications is they copied and pasted my code into three separate scrollable windows, separating HTML, CSS and JavaScript into separate boxes. I have looked everywhere and cannot find any way to do this, so I am perplexed.

Hopefully, someone will reply to this post and guide me to the proper formatting techniques so I don't get flagged.

Comment: Part 1: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked Part 2: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Side note: "better" with quotes comes out extremely rude in your post... Make sure that matches your intent (and even if it does consider removing that part).

Comment: You have 11 visible questions, most of them have 0 score. You haven't accepted any answer yet, even your own answers. Start by reading very carefully [ask] and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: On your most recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75194466/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-css-animation-to-run-more-than-one-time), you left a comment that expressed glowing thanks on an answer that seems to have answered your question. You did not, however, mark the answer as "accepted", or up-vote it. Whether right or wrong, many users consider voting a tit-for-tat proposition. Instead of posting effusive "thank you" comments, you might consider accepting or up-voting an answer.

Comment: Generally “well received” translates to 2 score or higher. You have a lot and non are “well received”. I’m guessing it’s the fact there are many questions, none are well received, and you have not accepted any (Mark’s comment)

Comment: Alexi, "better" was only intended to indicate that it was a comment on my question. I'm doing my best here to follow the rules and be a good participant. I look forward to the day I can contribute more.

Mark, I'll have to look more closely. When someone provides me a solution, I always comment and give thanks. I have not noticed any links to approve, or upvote. I'll go back and look now. I have read the document for How to Ask a Good Question and do not see any mention of approvals, or upvotes.

Comment: I  now see where I can accept and up-vote. I never noticed these and I'll begin to use them. If there is more thorough documentation for using this site, I'd find it helpful. How to Ask a Good Question does not mention these tools.

Comment: Re *"I have not noticed any links to approve, or upvote."*: That is an important data point for the usability folks. It doesn't really matter if a guide has been read or not. This is how the site is *actually* being used.

Comment: Formatting is not going to do it, it would be ridiculous if mere formatting would be the deciding factor since anyone can edit. It all boils down to having enough experience with a subject to ask questions others will find useful. Don't try to put ALL your questions on Stack Overflow, use other websites too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concerning the last part: This combination of code windows is called a **snippet**, and you can create it by clicking on the "<>" icon (see following screenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's your questions as they stand:

[image]

*Usually*, the kind of folks that get this warning and come to Meta about it are the sort of people that have questions that are downvoted or are closed in excess, but you've not got a lot of that going on.

- Your questions don't have a total negative score, and [this was the only question out of the lot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74923232/1079354) that had been downvoted at all.
- The questions themselves seem understandable and well-put together, so I wouldn't worry about getting dinged for that right now.

If anything else...I think your questions are fine.  I can't find any major critique with them at this point in time.

The system is *likely* firing this off because it does make sense to do so.  Of the nine questions you have on Stack Overflow, you have a net score of 2.  That's not a very good question-to-score ratio in general.

I'm not an SME in the technologies you're using so I would be very hesitant to find one of these questions "useful", but if nothing else, I don't think any of them are particularly bad.

Comment: What isn’t known is how many deleted questions the author has, I suspect, it’s more than one.

Comment: @SecurityHound:  I don't smell smoke, though.  Usually with deleted questions there's a clear pattern of poor question asking.  I'm not getting that from this.

Comment: Aside from this question (which was originally asked on SO then migrated here), the other deleted questions are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67049861), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67221662), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70429062). That latter one is a doozie, with a score of -7 and arguably spam. That, combined with the others, will be difficult to recover from. But hopefully some of those zero-score and one-score non-deleted questions that you show can be edited and improved to allow them to earn more votes. The warning is serving its purpose well here.

Comment: Makoto, thank you. I reviewed my question that was downvoted; however, I don't know why it was downvoted. It would be helpful to know what I did wrong, so I can improve. I also don't see anything indicating it was downvoted.

In addition, this post was downvoted. They crossed out the word "format" and replaced it with "format" (same word, same spelling). They crossed out the bold and replaced it with the same text, but not bolded. Then crossed out a comma and a period. Is bold text and a misplaced comma offensive??? I could be booted out for using a comma in the wrong place, really?

Comment: @MC Squared: Re *"crossed out the word "format" and replaced it with "format"*: That usually indicates formatting changes, though not in [this particular case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/422795/revisions) (spurious character removed?). It is easier to see in view ***"side-by-side Markdown"***. The usability folks have their work cut out for them.