# When I don't know which answer is correct, how should I choose the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, support

Today when I asked a question, I received the following reminder：*Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.*

**I do have many questions without accepted answers,** mainly because my existing knowledge is not enough to judge whether an answer is correct. I don't want to irresponsibly accept an answer that might mislead others into thinking it solves the problem. However, not accepting answers might limit my ability to ask further questions. What should I do?

---

Due to issues with the translation software, I mistakenly believed that this warning was due to my failure to accept an answer. Therefore, I thought my question approached the issue from a different perspective than the [other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked). As a result, I posted it separately, leading to an inadvertent duplication. However, I seem to be struggling to address this problem effectively at the moment. Since the question already has an answer, I cannot delete it. Additionally, it inadvertently overlaps with [another question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked) Despite my attempts to modify it, I cannot change this fact, leaving me uncertain about what to do.

Comment: I mean... if you don't see a specific answer as best, don't accept one. Not accepting an answer won't impact your ability to ask more.

Comment: The message you get is solely based on the score of your questions. Not related to accepting or not accepting answers. You should pre-emptively read [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583) which explains it.

Comment: The message that you were shown has **absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with** accepting answers.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No

Comment: Why did you mention the message, if you are not asking about it and it is unrelated to the problem that you want to solve?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That wasn't what I mentioned; someone added it after the question was closed!

Comment: @bokabokaboka then why doesn't that edit show up in the [revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/427013/revisions)? Maybe you added that message by accident?

Comment: To be clear, I'm talking about the part of your question **here**, that starts with: "Today when I asked a question, I received the following reminder". Why did you *tell us about* that happening, if you didn't want to discuss the fact that it happened and didn't want an answer that takes it into account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only accept answers you know to be correct. If you don't know, that's fine. The system is designed so that other users can vote on the answers they found most useful/correct, and those will rise to the top.

That warning doesn't say anything about accepting answers, and as far as I'm aware<sup>1</sup>, the algorithm doesn't take whether you've accepted an answer into account when deciding whether a question is well-received.  The most important factor for that is the question's score, though there are some other factors (such as if the account has a habit of deleting questions after they are answered).

---

<sup>1</sup> The exact details are a secret, even to moderators, but some information has been publicly revealed.